# Converting date to milliseconds, givse wrong result

Tags: java, date

I want to convert two dates to milliseconds, but the given result is wrong, is there anything wrong with code?, how to solve it otherwise...

```
GregorianCalendar c1 = new GregorianCalendar();
GregorianCalendar c2 = new GregorianCalendar();

c1.set(2013, 01, 31, 16, 44, 49);
c2.set(2013, 02, 01, 12, 59, 55);

System.out.println("c1 = "+c1.getTimeInMillis()+"\nc2 = "+ c2.getTimeInMillis());

output:
c1 = 1362300289619
c2 = 1362113995619
```

After caculating the time, it gives this result: `0Month -2Day  -3Hour  -44Min  -54Sec`
which is wrong. And must be something like this: `0Month 0Day  20Hour  15Min  6Sec`.

c1 is bigger then c2, because it gives wrong result, but why it happened that c1 become bigger then c2, in such case it is not possible to calculate the time between two dates.
if someone knows please help me, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Months are 0-based, so in your example, c1 is the 31st of February, which is interpreted as the 3rd of March (only 28 days in February) and c2 is on the 1st of March.

Comment: Thank you very much, the problem already solved, just by "monts-1"

Comment: c1.set(2013, 01-1, 31, 16, 44, 49);
c2.set(2013, 02-1, 01, 12, 59, 55);

Comment: Also note that `01` is an octal notation - it happens that `1` in octal is also `1` in decimal - but `09` won't work... So you should really write `c1.set(2013, 1-1, 31, 16, 44, 49);`.

Answer (score 5):

This code:

```
c1.set(2013, 01, 31, 16, 44, 49);
```

is trying to set *February* 31st, because Java months are 0-based. I suspect you're ending up with March 3rd, 3 days after February 28th. That is clearly after March 1st, which is what your `c2` is set to.

From the docs of [`Calendar.set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#set%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29):

> month - the value used to set the MONTH calendar field. Month value is 0-based. e.g., 0 for January.

Whenever you find your code behaving strangely, *always* check the details of any API call you're not 100% sure of.

As an alternative, I strongly suggest you use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) if at all possible - it's a *much* saner API.

Comment: Why joda time? if you dont know that items start with 0 its not javas fault. An external lib is not neccesary in his case. In professional developpment often an open source clearing is neccesarry when using another external lib.

Comment: @AlexWien: Because Joda Time has *far* fewer surprises like that. I agree that you should know whatever API you use - but you should also choose the sanest API you can. In terms of clearance - that's why I said "if at all possible". Sometimes it's not, but when you can, it's much better.

Answer (score 1):

> Thank you guys for your reply! The problem solved now, only by
> subtract 1 from months, before i don't know that in Java the months
> start from zero... this is how to solve
>
> c1.set(2013, (01-1), 31, 16, 44, 49);
> c2.set(2013, (02-1), 01, 12, 59, 55);

Instead you could use the constants on the `java.util.Calendar` class which will make your code easier to read.

```
c1.set(2013, Calendar.JANUARY, 31, 16, 44, 49);
c2.set(2013, Calendar.FEBRUARY, 01, 12, 59, 55);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for your reply!
The problem solved now, only by subtract 1 from months, before i don't know that in Java the months start from zero...
this is how to solved:

```
c1.set(2013, (01-1), 31, 16, 44, 49);
c2.set(2013, (02-1), 01, 12, 59, 55);
```

Comment: you don't need to do this, just click on the check mark under the answer that has helped your solve the problem (give the person who provided the answer credit for it..)